# how can i fixe :Data path "" must have required property 'browserTarget'

Tags: angular

i have a problem when i run my angular project ,when i use ng serve i get this error "Error: Schema validation failed with the following errors:
Data path "" must have required property 'browserTarget'."
and this is all the terminal "
"i get the problem when i tried to use json-server, i think can be part of the problem "

```
Node.js version v19.1.0 detected.
Odd numbered Node.js versions will not enter LTS status and should not be used for production. For more information, please see https://nodejs.org/en/about/previous-releases/.
Error: Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path "" must have required property 'browserTarget'.
C:\Users\Yousrii\Desktop\angular\firstApp\crud-app\node_modules\rxjs\dist\cjs\internal\util\reportUnhandledError.js:13
            throw err;
            ^

SchemaValidationException [Error]: Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path "" must have required property 'browserTarget'.
    at C:\Users\Yousrii\Desktop\angular\firstApp\crud-app\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\src\archrc\architect.js:40:27 {
  errors: [
    {
      instancePath: '',
      schemaPath: '#/required',
      keyword: 'required',
      params: { missingProperty: 'browserTarget' },
      message: "must have required property 'browserTarget'"
    }
  ]
}

Node.js v19.1.0
```

this my angular.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "crud-app": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss",
          "standalone": false
        },
        "@schematics/angular:directive": {
          "standalone": false
        },
        "@schematics/angular:pipe": {
          "standalone": false
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/crud-app",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "browser": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "server": "src/main.server.ts",
            "prerender": true,
            "ssr": {
              "entry": "server.ts"
            }
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "crud-app:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "crud-app:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "crud-app:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": "f5eaf23b-c76d-4b17-9b8e-7f364037bd80"
  }
}
```

any help ??

i tried to make update but nothing changed

Comment: To fix this issue, you need to update the serve configuration in your angular.json file. Replace the buildTarget property with browserTarget, and set the value to the desired build configuration (e.g., crud-app:build:development).
  then run Ng serve